# How to skip line in txt file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, backend

I have a wordlist and the first line got the word **'**password**'** , I want to skip this word

```
wordlist = open(r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\10k most passwords.txt')


number_of_lines = 1

for i in range(number_of_lines):
    
    line = wordlist.readline()
    if line == 'password':
        break
    
    else:
        print(line.split()[0])
```

It keeps printing '`password`'

How could I make it skip this line to print the second line?

Is there a way to print a specific line like only the line number 100 ?

Comment: i highly recommend to use context manager `with open ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'continue' instead of break

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 [ word for word in wordlist if not word.strip().startswith(“password”) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if you looking to skip the first line, then you can do:

```py
with open(r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\10k most passwords.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines()[1:]:
        print(line)
```